# I'm using CAT simulation and I added sonars to the jeep in the simulation using hector gazebo but I keep getting an error in rviz

Tags: ros, sonar

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I keep getting the error " Transform [sender=unknown publisher]For frame [/sonar link]: Frame [/sonar link] does not exist "

I tried all the solutions provided in the ROS answers but still I face this issue.

Changes that I made to the simulation files:

1. Added sonar in the .xacro file, .gazebo file.

2.Also added the static transform publisher in the .launch file as

3.I ran the rosrun --debug rviz rviz and tried publishing the link.

4.I made changes to the gazebo_ros_sonar.cpp in the hector gazebo package.

But I still getting the error while running rviz and adding the sonar in it.

Please, suggest me an alternative possible solutions. ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/258921/i%27m-using-cat-simulation-and-i-added-sonars-to-the-jeep-in-the-simulation-using-hector-gazebo-but-i-keep-getting-an-error-in-rviz./) by [nishad](https://answers.ros.org/users/29985/nishad/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-04-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem is the name of the frame that needs to be exactly as the name of the link.
Example:

```
<link name="sonar1_link">
...
</link>
<plugin ...>
        ...
        <frameId>sonar1_link</frameId>
</plugin>
```

---

Originally posted by [SorinV](https://answers.ros.org/users/30485/sorinv/) with karma: 106 on 2017-05-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0